# regexp for checking the full name

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to write a regexp to check if the user inserted at least two words separated by at least one empty space:

Example:

```
var regexp = new RegExp(/^[a-z,',-]+(\s)[a-z,',-]+$/i);

regexp.test("D'avid Camp-Bel"); // true
regexp.test("John ---"); // true // but it should be false!
```

Comment: And what [did you try](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Answer hint: `var regexp = /^[a-z]+\s[a-z ]+$/i;` (an answer has to explain this pattern).

Comment: `\w` - is ANY symbol for naming vars, like [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Comment: @loldop - there are some chars that are valid in var names but aren't matched by that pattern.

Comment: yes for sure some of this characters will be `'`, `-`

Comment: `-` isn't valid in var names. I was thinking `$`, probably one or two others.

Comment: `RegExp` expects a **string** as argument, not a regular expression literal. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: I would relax your checks, what about "John F. Kennedy" or "Günther Schmit"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Does `^[a-z]([-']?[a-z]+)*( [a-z]([-']?[a-z]+)*)+$` work for you?

`[a-z]` ensures that a name always starts with a letter, then `[-']?[a-z]+` allows for a seperating character as long as it's followed by at least another letter. `*` allows for any number of these parts.

The second half, `( [a-z]([-']?[a-z]+)*)` matches a space followed by another name of the same pattern. `+` makes sure at least one additional name is present, but allows for more. (`{1,2}` could be used if you want to allow only two or three part names.

Comment: this doesn't support extended latin letters :/

Answer (score 7):

Simpler version

```
    /^([\w]{3,})+\s+([\w\s]{3,})+$/i
```

**([\w]{3,})** the first name should contain only letters and of length 3 or more

**+\s** the first name should be followed by a space

**+([\w\s]{3,})+** the second name should contain only letters of length 3 or more and can be followed by other names or not

**/i** ignores the case of the letters. Can be uppercase or lowercase letters

Comment: how make to accept unicode chars too?

Comment: this doesn't support extended latin letters :/

Comment: How this prevents the user from adding numbers?

Comment: @dellasavia @JoelBonetR this will prevent numbers and accept unicodes too `/^([\p{L}]{3,})+\s+([\p{L}\s]{3,})+$/iu`

Comment: `\p{L}` matches a character in the letter unicode category.

Answer (score 2):

This version allows accented characters and works fine for me!

```
^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú]{2,})+\s+([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú\s]{2,})+$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+(([',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/g
```

Comment: please improve your answer with more details and an example

Answer (score 0):

This answer also supports unicode characters.

```
^[\p{L}]([-']?[\p{L}]+)*( [\p{L}]([-']?[\p{L}]+)*)+$
```

Answer (score -1):

A couple of points:

1. In JavaScript it's generally better to use literals rather than named constructors (so `/pattern/` rather than `new RegExp()`. (Sure, there are times when you need the constructor route).
2. If you do use the constructor, in the case of RegExp you don't need the delimiting forward slashes
3. Your current pattern matches only the first word
4. `{1,}` can be written with the modifier `+`

Try

```
/^([a-z']+(-| )?)+$/i
```

Note the surname allows for double-barrel surnames.

Comment: You forgot about `David Campt Junior`. I think `/^([a-z]+(-| )?)+$/i` fits great

Comment: But in your case `David ----` is name. In mine `David-` is name, so both regexps are not perfect..

Comment: +1. Edited - ta. I mistakenly thought he wanted to match two names, but he in fact says "at least two".

Comment: `regexp.test("D'Devid Mark"); --> false`and it should be true.